# Kafka reabalance issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-interactive-queries

I am facing some issues with Kafka where we get the each product data in form of XML from one application through Kafka and we then using spark streaming , process the XML and insert data into hive. Each product XML takes around 30-40 seconds to process so we set consumer poll to 60 seconds so that it can poll next records after 60 seconds. 
We will have to process 90k product XML records and this activity is only for one time then after that whatever products gets updated in my application those only would go through Kafka and ingest into data lake.

As there are 14 partitions in topic , consumer reads the records from partitions and do the work but if we add one more instance/consumer in consumer group then it starts failing and gives the below error.

org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

What I understood from this error is that if its taking a lot of time to process the records and if we don’t poll long then group co-ordinator might assume that consumer is dead and trigger rebalance activity.
In such cases rebalance is triggered either because of we didn’t poll for a while or something else went wrong and current partition takes away then assign to other consumer so in such cases , we want to commit whatever we have already processed before ownership of partition is taken away and new owner of partition is supposed to start consuming it from last committed offset.

To commit the particular offset , we can keep committing intermediate offset instead of having commited current offset in the end ,and to know when the rebalance is triggered so we can commit those we have already processed, we added rebalance listener API to consumer which it first revoke the partition , commit the offsets and then assign it to other partition.

Kafka rebalance listener API allows us to specify consumer rebalance listener class which have two methods onPartitionsRevoked and onPartitionsAssigned.
onPartitionsRevoked method just before it takes away the partition so we can commit our current offset .
onPartitionsAssigned method right after rebalance listener is complete and before it start consuming records from new partitions.

When go-live , we need to work with 14 consumers to process 90k records parallelly so we have added rebalance listener class to achieve this (code is attached). 
Using rebalance listener API ,when we add another consumer then rebalance will be triggered because we have new consumer and will have new partitions to read and then Kafka will revoke all partitions from first consumer because list of consumer in group is modified and both of consumers will get new partitions assigned then each of them would get same number of different partition.

After all this , same issue still persists. Could you guys please help us to resolve this.

Consumer Config values:

metric.reporters = []
                metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
                partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
                reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
                sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
                max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
                bootstrap.servers = [d.messagebroker.genmills.com:9092, d.messagebroker.genmills.com:9092]
                ssl.keystore.type = JKS
                enable.auto.commit = false
                sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
                interceptor.classes = null
                exclude.internal.topics = true
                ssl.truststore.password = null
                client.id = consumer-1
                ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
                max.poll.records = 1
                check.crcs = true
                request.timeout.ms = 40000
                heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
                auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
                receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
                ssl.truststore.type = JKS
                ssl.truststore.location = null
                ssl.keystore.password = null
                fetch.min.bytes = 1
                send.buffer.bytes = 131072
                value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                group.id = PIM-Consumer
                retry.backoff.ms = 100
                ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
                sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
                sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
                sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
                ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
                ssl.key.password = null
                fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
                sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
                connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
                session.timeout.ms = 30000
                metrics.num.samples = 2
                key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                ssl.protocol = TLS
                ssl.provider = null
                ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
                ssl.keystore.location = null
                ssl.cipher.suites = null
                security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
                ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
                metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
                auto.offset.reset = latest

my code:

```
      while (true) {
        val record = consumer.poll(60000)
        if (record != null) {
          println("record count" + record.count())
          var scalaRecords = record.asScala.toList
          if (scalaRecords.nonEmpty) {
            scalaRecords.foreach(record => {
              var messageValue = (record.value).toString
              println("start timestamp - > " + LocalDateTime.now().toString)
              try {
                if (messageValue.length >= 2 && (messageValue.charAt(0) == '"') && (messageValue.charAt(messageValue.length - 1) == '"')) {
                  var message = messageValue.substring(1, messageValue.length - 1);
                  xmltags_check(message)
                }
                else {
                  xmltags_check(messageValue)
                }
                rebalanceListner.addoffset(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset());
                consumer.commitSync(rebalanceListner.getCurrentoffsets());
              }
              catch {
                case e: Exception =>
                  logError(s"Failed to process Message{$messageValue} with error details{$e}")
              }
              println("end timestamp - > " + LocalDateTime.now().toString)
            }
            )
          }

        } else {
          logInfo(s"running step to data lake- in else no record found")
        }

      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logError(s"Failed to poll records from consumer{$e}")
    }

rebalancelistner :-


import java.util.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;

public class RebalanceListner implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
    private KafkaConsumer consumer;
    private Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> currentoffsets = new HashMap();

    public RebalanceListner(KafkaConsumer con){
        this.consumer=con;
    }
    public void addoffset(String topic, int partition, long offset ){
        currentoffsets.put(new TopicPartition(topic, partition),new OffsetAndMetadata(offset,"commit"));
    }
    public Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> getCurrentoffsets(){
        return currentoffsets;
    }
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions){
        System.out.println("Following Partition Assigned ..");
        for(TopicPartition  partition: partitions)
            System.out.println(partition.partition()+",");
    }
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions){
        System.out.println("Following Partition Revoked ..");
        for(TopicPartition  partition: partitions)
            System.out.println(partition.partition()+",");
        System.out.println("Following Partition Commited ..");
        for(TopicPartition tp: currentoffsets.keySet())
            System.out.println(tp.partition());
        consumer.commitSync(currentoffsets);
        currentoffsets.clear();
    }
}
```